# unable to insert query in MariaDB

Tags: odbc, mariadb-10.1, mariadb-10.5

I am trying to insert a query :
`insert into Table(ID,Value,Date) Values('Test1', '33', '20210315 11:15:27.059')`
to MariaDB using ODBC Driver (Maria 3.1) but I have this error :

> Exception message : ERROR [22007]
> [ma-3.1.11][10.2.15-MariaDB]Incorrect datetime value: '20210315
> 11:15:27.059' for column 'date' at row 1 I think that this format
> '20210315 11:15:27.059'is unsupportable by MariaDB.

Could you please help me to change the time format from the database.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I forget the exact rules for what formats are acceptable as date/timestamp literals.  However, I'm sure that the following format is acceptable:

```
2021-03-15 11:15:27.059
```

Your updated code:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (ID, Value, Date)
VALUES ('Test1', '33', '2021-03-15 11:15:27.059');
```

### Demo

Comment: thank you but I need this format 20210315 11:15:27.059
is there a way to change the date format from the Databases to support it?

Comment: @happy Dates/timestamps have no internal "format," they are stored as binary.  If you want to _view_ your timestamp this way, then use the `DATE_FORMAT` function with the mask you want.

Comment: could you help me on how to use the DATE_FORMAT function?

Comment: I executed it but I have this error :
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(2021031015 11:46:23.320, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')' at line 1 */

DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')' at line 1 */

Comment: @happy [Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=60aa9626e163fe148edd9005c7fca6a1)

Comment: Read the above comment which has a working demo.

Comment: I used the same query on HeidiSql the query executed and the table is created but the format of the date displayed is 2021-03-15 11:15:27.059' I need that the format of the column date displayed in the table is as the following  '20210315 11:15:27.059'.

Comment: Your question has been answered.  If you have other requirements, please open a new question.